# Group by multiple columns in dplyr, using string vector input

Tags: r, dplyr, r-faq

I'm trying to transfer my understanding of plyr into dplyr, but I can't figure out how to group by multiple columns.

```
# make data with weird column names that can't be hard coded
data = data.frame(
  asihckhdoydkhxiydfgfTgdsx = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
  a30mvxigxkghc5cdsvxvyv0ja = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
  value = rnorm(100)
)

# get the columns we want to average within
columns = names(data)[-3]

# plyr - works
ddply(data, columns, summarize, value=mean(value))

# dplyr - raises error
data %.%
  group_by(columns) %.%
  summarise(Value = mean(value))
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : index out of bounds
```

What am I missing to translate the plyr example into a dplyr-esque syntax?

**Edit 2017**: Dplyr has been updated, so a simpler solution is available. See the currently selected answer.

Comment: Just got here as it was top google. You can use `group_by_` now explained in `vignette("nse")`

Comment: @kungfujam: That appears to only group by the first column, not the pair of columns

Comment: You need to use `.dots`. Here's the solution adapted from @hadley 's answer below:
`df %>% group_by_(.dots=list(quote(asihckhdoydk), quote(a30mvxigxkgh))) %>% summarise(n = n())`

Comment: Have put full code in an answer below

Comment: As someone pointed out in an answer on the comment, the aim is to not require hardcoded column names.

Comment: updated my answer below to reflect this

Comment: dplyr now includes scoped grouping verbs, i.e., `group_by_at`, so you don't have to much around with quoting and symbols. Example code in my answer below.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Since this question was posted, dplyr added scoped versions of `group_by` ([documentation here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.1/topics/group_by_all)). This lets you use the same functions you would use with `select`, like so:

```
data = data.frame(
    asihckhdoydkhxiydfgfTgdsx = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
    a30mvxigxkghc5cdsvxvyv0ja = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
    value = rnorm(100)
)

# get the columns we want to average within
columns = names(data)[-3]

library(dplyr)
df1 <- data %>%
  group_by_at(vars(one_of(columns))) %>%
  summarize(Value = mean(value))

#compare plyr for reference
df2 <- plyr::ddply(data, columns, plyr::summarize, value=mean(value))
table(df1 == df2, useNA = 'ifany')
## TRUE 
##  27
```

The output from your example question is as expected (see comparison to plyr above and output below):

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   asihckhdoydkhxiydfgfTgdsx [?]
  asihckhdoydkhxiydfgfTgdsx a30mvxigxkghc5cdsvxvyv0ja       Value
                     <fctr>                    <fctr>       <dbl>
1                         A                         A  0.04095002
2                         A                         B  0.24943935
3                         A                         C -0.25783892
4                         B                         A  0.15161805
5                         B                         B  0.27189974
6                         B                         C  0.20858897
7                         C                         A  0.19502221
8                         C                         B  0.56837548
9                         C                         C -0.22682998
```

Note that since `dplyr::summarize` only strips off one layer of grouping at a time, you've still got some grouping going on in the resultant tibble (which can sometime catch people by suprise later down the line). If you want to be absolutely safe from unexpected grouping behavior, you can always add `%>% ungroup` to your pipeline after you summarize.

Comment: does update to `0.7.0` make the quote-unquote system available with several columns, too?

Comment: You can also use the `.dots` arguments to `group_by()` as such: `data %>%  group_by(.dots = columns) %>% summarize(value = mean(value))`.

Comment: Does the call to `one_of()` do anything here? I think it is redundant in this context, as the expression is wrapped in a call to `vars()`.

Comment: @Khashir yes, this answer still works
@knowah You're right, the call to `one_of()` is redundant in this context

Comment: How would you apply this solution if you wanted the mean of multiple columns? Say you have `value_A` and `value_B` in your input, and you want to have a mean for each of the columns based on `group_by`? could you just do `...summarize(Mean_A = value_A, Mean_B = value_B)`?

Comment: @Sos To apply a function across multiple columns using `select` syntax, see the new `across` function: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html
In your case, it would look something like `summarize(across(all_of(c(''value_A", "value_B")), mean))`

Answer (score 105):

Just so as to write the code in full, here's an update on Hadley's answer with the new syntax:

```
library(dplyr)

df <-  data.frame(
    asihckhdoydk = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
    a30mvxigxkgh = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
    value = rnorm(100)
)

# Columns you want to group by
grp_cols <- names(df)[-3]

# Convert character vector to list of symbols
dots <- lapply(grp_cols, as.symbol)

# Perform frequency counts
df %>%
    group_by_(.dots=dots) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
```

output:

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: asihckhdoydk

  asihckhdoydk a30mvxigxkgh  n
1            A            A 10
2            A            B 10
3            A            C 13
4            B            A 14
5            B            B 10
6            B            C 12
7            C            A  9
8            C            B 12
9            C            C 10
```

Comment: This seems to still be hardcoding the column names, just in a formula instead. The point of the question is how to use strings so as to not have to type `asihckhdoydk`...

Comment: Have updated solution using `dots <- lapply(names(df)[-3], function(x) as.symbol(x))` to create the `.dots` argument

Comment: trying to sort through these answers, `.dots=` was the crucial step.  if someone has a good handle on why that's required in the `group_by` call, can you edit this answer?  right now it's a bit inscrutable.

Comment: `vignette("nse")` indicates there are three ways to quote that are acceptable: formula, quote, and character. Unless you are worried about which environment it will pull from, you can probably get away with `group_by_(.dots=grp_cols)`

Answer (score 58):

The support for this in dplyr is currently pretty weak, eventually I think the syntax will be something like:

```
df %.% group_by(.groups = c("asdfgfTgdsx", "asdfk30v0ja"))
```

But that probably won't be there for a while (because I need to think through all the consequences).

In the meantime, you can use `regroup()`, which takes a list of symbols:

```
library(dplyr)

df <-  data.frame(
  asihckhdoydk = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
  a30mvxigxkgh = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
  value = rnorm(100)
)

df %.%
  regroup(list(quote(asihckhdoydk), quote(a30mvxigxkgh))) %.%
  summarise(n = n())
```

If you have have a character vector of column names, you can convert them to the right structure with `lapply()` and `as.symbol()`:

```
vars <- setdiff(names(df), "value")
vars2 <- lapply(vars, as.symbol)

df %.% regroup(vars2) %.% summarise(n = n())
```

Comment: `as.symbol` solves it. Thanks! In case it helps with development: this scenario is a really common one for me. Aggregate a numerical result over every combination of the other variables.

Comment: apparently this only works for this particular example and no other.

Comment: I originally marked this as the answer, but updates to dplyr allow kungfujam's answer to work.

Comment: `regroup` is also deprecated (at least as of version 0.4.3).

Answer (score 29):

### Update with across() from dplyr 1.0.0

All the answers above are still working, and the solutions with the .dots argument are intruiging.

BUT if you look for a solution that is easier to remember, the new `across()` comes in handy. It was published 2020-04-03 by Hadley Wickham and can be used in `mutate()` and `summarise()` and replace the scoped variants like `_at` or `_all`. Above all, it replaces very elegantly the cumbersome non-standard evaluation (NSE) with quoting/unquoting such as `!!! rlang::syms()`.

So the solution with `across` looks very readable:

```
data %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(columns))) %>%
  summarize(Value = mean(value))
```

Comment: This is a more intuitive way compared to `.dots` IMHO.

Comment: I was looking for the most recent good (best?) practice, and this looks like it

Answer (score 27):

String specification of columns in `dplyr` are now supported through variants of the `dplyr` functions with names finishing in an underscore. For example, corresponding to the `group_by` function there is a `group_by_` function that may take string arguments. [This vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) describes the syntax of these functions in detail.

The following snippet cleanly solves the problem that @sharoz originally posed (note the need to write out the `.dots` argument):

```
# Given data and columns from the OP

data %>%
    group_by_(.dots = columns) %>%
    summarise(Value = mean(value))
```

(Note that dplyr now uses the `%>%` operator, and `%.%` is deprecated).

Answer (score 17):

Until dplyr has full support for string arguments, perhaps this gist is useful:

https://gist.github.com/skranz/9681509

It contains bunch of wrapper functions like s_group_by, s_mutate, s_filter, etc that use string arguments. You can mix them with the normal dplyr functions. For example

```
cols = c("cyl","gear")
mtcars %.%
  s_group_by(cols) %.%  
  s_summarise("avdisp=mean(disp), max(disp)") %.%
  arrange(avdisp)
```

Answer (score 10):

It works if you pass it the objects (well, you aren't, but...) rather than as a character vector:

```
df %.%
    group_by(asdfgfTgdsx, asdfk30v0ja) %.%
    summarise(Value = mean(value))

> df %.%
+   group_by(asdfgfTgdsx, asdfk30v0ja) %.%
+   summarise(Value = mean(value))
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: asdfgfTgdsx

  asdfgfTgdsx asdfk30v0ja        Value
1           A           C  0.046538002
2           C           B -0.286359899
3           B           A -0.305159419
4           C           A -0.004741504
5           B           B  0.520126476
6           C           C  0.086805492
7           B           C -0.052613078
8           A           A  0.368410146
9           A           B  0.088462212
```

where `df` was your `data`.

`?group_by` says:

```
 ...: variables to group by. All tbls accept variable names, some
      will also accept functons of variables. Duplicated groups
      will be silently dropped.
```

which I interpret to mean not the character versions of the names, but how you would refer to them in `foo$bar`; `bar` is not quoted here. Or how you'd refer to variables in a formula: `foo ~ bar`.

@Arun also mentions that you can do:

```
df %.%
    group_by("asdfgfTgdsx", "asdfk30v0ja") %.%
    summarise(Value = mean(value))
```

But you can't pass in something that *unevaluated* is not a name of a variable in the data object.

I presume this is due to the internal methods Hadley is using to look up the things you pass in via the `...` argument.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for that. I hadn't noticed that, but it too makes sense. I added a note to this regard, citing you and your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't rely on hard coding the column names. I'm trying to do this without having to specify them.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = data.frame(
  my.a = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
  my.b = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
  value = rnorm(100)
)

group_by(data,newcol=paste(my.a,my.b,sep="_")) %>% summarise(Value=mean(value))
```

Answer (score 4):

One (tiny) case that is missing from the answers here, that I wanted to make explicit, is when the variables to group by are generated dynamically midstream in a pipeline:

```
library(wakefield)
df_foo = r_series(rnorm, 10, 1000)
df_foo %>% 
  # 1. create quantized versions of base variables
  mutate_each(
    funs(Quantized = . > 0)
  ) %>% 
  # 2. group_by the indicator variables
  group_by_(
    .dots = grep("Quantized", names(.), value = TRUE)
    ) %>% 
  # 3. summarize the base variables
  summarize_each(
    funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)), contains("X_")
  )
```

This basically shows how to use `grep` in conjunction with `group_by_(.dots = ...)` to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

General example on using the `.dots` argument as character vector input to the `dplyr::group_by` function :

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(.dots ="Species") %>% 
    summarise(meanpetallength = mean(Petal.Length))
```

Or without a hard coded name for the grouping variable (as asked by the OP):

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(.dots = names(iris)[5]) %>% 
    summarise_at("Petal.Length", mean)
```

With the example of the OP:

```
data %>% 
    group_by(.dots =names(data)[-3]) %>% 
    summarise_at("value", mean)
```

See also the [dplyr vignette on programming](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) which explains pronouns, quasiquotation, quosures, and tidyeval.