# specify dplyr column names

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

How can I pass column names to dplyr if I do not know the column name, but want to specify it through a variable?

e.g. this works:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(1:9),ncol=3,nrow=3))
df$group <- c("A","B","A")
gdf <- df %.% group_by(group) %.% summarise(m1 =mean(V1),m2 =mean(V2),m3 =mean(V3))
```

But this does not

```
require(dplyr)
someColumn = "group"
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(1:9),ncol=3,nrow=3))
df$group <- c("A","B","A")
gdf <- df %.% group_by(someColumn) %.% summarise(m1 =mean(V1),m2 =mean(V2),m3 =mean(V3))
```

Comment: yes possibly. I ended up renaming the group column before the dplyr chain. something like
    `colnames(df)[which(colnames(df)==someColumn)] <- "group"`

Comment: It is worth noting that the 'correct' answer probably differs from the solutions below under dplyr 0.7.0.

Answer (score 19):

I just gave a similar answer over at [Group by multiple columns in dplyr, using string vector input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208801/group-by-multiple-columns-in-dplyr-using-string-vector-input), but for good measure: functions that allow you to operate on columns using strings have been added to `dplyr`. These have the same name as the regular `dplyr` functions, but end in an underscore. The functions are described in detail in [this vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html).

Given `df` and `someColumn` from the OP, this now works a treat:

```
gdf <- df %>% group_by_(someColumn) %>% summarise(m1=mean(V1),m2=mean(V2),m3=mean(V3))
```

Note that it is `group_by_`, rather than `group_by`, and the `%>%` operator is used as `%.%` is deprecated.

Comment: Can you specify `m1` to be the name of a variable passed in a function?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer to this straightforward question, obtained by picking through hadley's solution to his posted dupe.

```
gdf <- df %.% regroup( lapply( someColumn, as.symbol)) %.% summarise(m1 =mean(V1),m2 =mean(V2),m3 =mean(V3))
```

FWIW, my use case involved grouping by one variable column and one constant column.  The solution to that is:

```
gdf <- df %.% regroup( lapply( c( 'constant_column', someColumn), as.symbol)) %.% summarise(m1 =mean(V1),m2 =mean(V2),m3 =mean(V3))
```

Finally, the posted `eval` solution doesn't work.  That just makes a new column whose values are all what `someColumn` `eval`s to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use summarise_  as follow:

```
plotVar         = "Stocks_US_TotalCrudeOil"
dfBand <- mydf[ c( plotVar ,  "year", "week"  )  ] %>%
            filter ( year %in% bandYears )   %>%
            group_by (  week )   %>% 
            summarise_ (   ymini =  paste( "min(" ,  as.name(plotVar)  ,")"  ) 
                         , ymaxi =  paste( "max(" ,  as.name(plotVar)  ,")"  )     )
dfBand
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
pollutant <- "sulfate"
summarise(data, mean(eval(as.symbol(pollutant)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

I was trying to ask the same question for my own problem. Then I found a solution to it.
I encapsulate the expression with eval(as.symbol()).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with my current version of dplyr

Answer (score -2):

I expect you just have to use eval

```
require(dplyr)
someColumn = "group"
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(1:9),ncol=3,nrow=3))
df$group <- c("A","B","A")
gdf <- df %.% group_by(eval(someColumn)) %.% summarise(m1 =mean(V1),m2 =mean(V2),m3 =mean(V3))
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all, just adds a new column called `eval(someColumn)` where every row is `"group"`.