# standard evaluation in dplyr: summarise a variable given as a character string

Tags: r, dplyr

**UPDATE July 2020:**

`dplyr` 1.0 has changed pretty much everything about this question as well as all of the answers. See the `dplyr` programming vignette here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

The new way to refer to columns when their identifier is stored as a character vector is to use the `.data` pronoun from `rlang`, and then subset as you would in base R.

```
library(dplyr)

key <- "v3"
val <- "v2"
drp <- "v1"

df <- tibble(v1 = 1:5, v2 = 6:10, v3 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2)))

df %>% 
    select(-matches(drp)) %>% 
    group_by(.data[[key]]) %>% 
    summarise(total = sum(.data[[val]], na.rm = TRUE))

#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   v3    total
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 A        21
#> 2 B        19
```

If your code is in a package function, you can `@importFrom rlang .data` to avoid R check notes about undefined globals.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I want to refer to an unknown column name inside a `summarise`. The standard evaluation functions introduced in `dplyr 0.3` allow column names to be referenced using variables, but this doesn't appear to work when you call a `base` R function within e.g. a `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)
 
key <- "v3"
val <- "v2"
drp <- "v1"
 
df <- data_frame(v1 = 1:5, v2 = 6:10, v3 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2)))
```

The df looks like this:

```
> df
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]

  v1 v2 v3
1  1  6  A
2  2  7  A
3  3  8  A
4  4  9  B
5  5 10  B
```

I want to drop v1, group by v3, and sum v2 for each group:

```
df %>% select(-matches(drp)) %>% group_by_(key) %>% summarise_(sum(val, na.rm = TRUE))

Error in sum(val, na.rm = TRUE) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

The NSE version of `select()` works fine, since it can match a character string. The SE version of `group_by()` works fine, since it can now accept variables as arguments and evaluate them. However, I haven't found a way to achieve similar results when using base R functions inside `dplyr` functions.

Things that don't work:

```
df %>% group_by_(key) %>% summarise_(sum(get(val), na.rm = TRUE))
Error in get(val) : object 'v2' not found

df %>% group_by_(key) %>% summarise_(sum(eval(as.symbol(val)), na.rm = TRUE))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'v2' not found
```

I've checked out [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208801/group-by-multiple-columns-in-dplyr-using-string-vector-input) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390141/specify-dplyr-column-names) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492280/non-standard-evaluation-nse-in-dplyrs-filter-pulling-data-from-mysql), but none of the proposed solutions have worked for me so far.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`dplyr` 1.0 has changed pretty much everything about this question as well as all of the answers. See the `dplyr` programming vignette here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

The new way to refer to columns when their identifier is stored as a character vector is to use the `.data` pronoun from `rlang`, and then subset as you would in base R.

```
library(dplyr)

key <- "v3"
val <- "v2"
drp <- "v1"

df <- tibble(v1 = 1:5, v2 = 6:10, v3 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2)))

df %>% 
    select(-matches(drp)) %>% 
    group_by(.data[[key]]) %>% 
    summarise(total = sum(.data[[val]], na.rm = TRUE))

#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   v3    total
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 A        21
#> 2 B        19
```

If your code is in a package function, you can `@importFrom rlang .data` to avoid R check notes about undefined globals.

Comment: For package authors that use 'dplyr' in their package, this approach makes life *much* easier when submitting the package to CRAN

Answer (score 55):

Please note that this answer does *not* apply to `dplyr >= 0.7.0`, but to previous versions.

> [[`dplyr 0.7.0`]](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/news.html) has a new approach to non-standard evaluation (NSE) called tidyeval. It is described in detail in `vignette("programming")`.

---

The [`dplyr` vignette on non-standard evalutation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) is helpful here. Check the section "Mixing constants and variables" and you find that the function `interp` from package `lazyeval` could be used, and "[u]se `as.name` if you have a character string that gives a variable name":

```
library(lazyeval)
df %>%
  select(-matches(drp)) %>%
  group_by_(key) %>%
  summarise_(sum_val = interp(~sum(var, na.rm = TRUE), var = as.name(val)))
#   v3 sum_val
# 1  A      21
# 2  B      19
```

Comment: I read through the vignette earlier, but was misusing `interp` in my tests. Thank you!

Comment: I still cannot get it to work despite this answer and the vignette. I don't have a MWE. I perform a summarise `summarise(ng,median=median(total_length) )`, which works because 'total_length' is a column name in my data.frame 'ng'. Now I want to loop over column name stored in a list 'features', in this example that would be `summarise(ng,median=median(features[8]) )`. But that gives the string 'features[8]' in the summary. The method with interp `summarise(ng,median= interp(~median(var), var = features[8]) )` gives an error: 'Error: not a vector'. What to do???

Answer (score 42):

With the release of the rlang package and the 0.7.0 update to dplyr, this is now fairly simple.

When you want to use a character string (e.g. "v1") as a variable name, you just:

1. Convert the string to a symbol using `sym()` from the rlang package
2. In your function call, write `!!` in front of the symbol

For instance, you'd do the following:

```
my_var <- "Sepal.Length"
my_sym <- sym(my_var)
summarize(iris, Mean = mean(!!my_sym))
```

More compactly, you could combine the step of converting your string to a symbol with `sym()` and prefixing it with `!!` when writing your function call.

For instance, you could write:

```
my_var <- "Sepal.Length"
summarize(iris, mean(!!sym(my_var)))
```

To return to your original example, you could do the following:

```
library(rlang)

key <- "v3"
val <- "v2"
drp <- "v1"

df <- data_frame(v1 = 1:5, v2 = 6:10, v3 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2)))

df %>% 
  # NOTE: we don't have to do anything to `drp`
  # since the matches() function expects a character string
  select(-matches(drp)) %>% 
  group_by(!!sym(key)) %>% 
  summarise(sum(!!sym(val), na.rm = TRUE))
```

**Alternative Syntax**

With the release of rlang version 0.4.0, you can use the following syntax:

```
my_var <- "Sepal.Length"
my_sym <- sym(my_var)
summarize(iris, Mean = mean({{ my_sym }}))
```

Instead of writing `!!my_sym`, you can write `{{ my_sym }}`. This has the advantage of being arguably clearer, but has the disadvantage that you have to convert the string to a symbol before placing it inside the brackets. For instance, you can write `!!sym(my_var)` but you *can't* write `{{sym(my_var)}}`

**Additional details**

Of all the official documentation explaining how the usage of `sym()` and `!!` works, these seem to be the most accessible:

1. [dplyr vignette: Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)
2. [The section of Hadley Wickham's book 'Advanced R' on metaprogramming](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html)

Comment: what if there is more than one variable?

Comment: [Here's the answer to that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55869639/5373794) in a related SO question.

Answer (score 9):

Pass the `.dots` argument a list of strings constructing the strings using `paste`, `sprintf` or using string interpolation from package gsubfn via `fn$list` in place of `list` as we do here:

```
library(gsubfn)
df %>% 
   group_by_(key) %>% 
   summarise_(.dots = fn$list(mean = "mean($val)", sd = "sd($val)"))
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

  v3 mean        sd
1  A  7.0 1.0000000
2  B  9.5 0.7071068
```

Answer (score 8):

New dplyr update:

The new functionality of dplyr can help with this. Instead of strings for the variables that need non-standard evaluation, we use quosures `quo()`. We undo the quoting with another function `!!`. For more on these [see this vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). You will need the [developer's version of dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr) until the full release.

```
library(dplyr) #0.5.0.9004+
key <- quo(v3)
val <- quo(v2)
drp <- "v1"

df <- data_frame(v1 = 1:5, v2 = 6:10, v3 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2)))
df %>% select(-matches("v1")) %>% 
  group_by(!!key) %>% 
  summarise(sum(!!val, na.rm = TRUE))
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#      v3 `sum(v2, na.rm = TRUE)`
#   <chr>                   <int>
# 1     A                      21
# 2     B                      19
```

Comment: Reading the [programming with dplyr vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) has fundamentally changed the way I program function parameters. To provide unquoted variable names as function parameters, see also the examples using  `enquo()` and `!!` in the `my_summarise` function in that vignette.