# How to create one excel workbook with multiple sheets in it where each sheet is a data frame

Tags: r, excel

I have to calculate aggregate of 50 variables(categorical) with respect to 1 variable(a)
after finding out, I want to create 50 sheets in a single excel workbook where each sheet will look like:-
"variable name"  a
  1              10
  2              21
  3              18
  .
  .

and so on.

I`m able to create 50 csv and then merge them into 1 workbook but this is long process.
What I want is to get a function in which a loop will run , will calculate aggregate and then write in a sheet in the workbook; do this for all 50 times(variables)

package:- WriteXLS was used by me.

Comment: variable name       1          2            3             4


a                           10        21          14            56

Comment: WriteXLS(c("HELP", "helpfemale",.....for all 50 varaibles), "newhelp.xls") .  this is one way to do but it is tedious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: easy way to export multiple data.frame to multiple excel worksheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713310/r-easy-way-to-export-multiple-data-frame-to-multiple-excel-worksheets)

Comment: @Adama No, I have checked

Comment: @Adama This is definitely a duplicate of the post you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that involves two steps: 1) getting your summary statistics for each variable as separate data frames in a list, and then 2) writing the elements of that list as separate sheets in an Excel workbook. I used `iris` as the test bed and used `xlsx` instead of `WriteXLS` because it makes appending sheets easier.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)
library(xlsx)

# Start with a function to get your summary stats by id
aggregateit <- function(x) {
    require(dplyr)
    require(lazyeval)
    result <- iris %>%  # need to name your initial df here
        group_by(Species) %>%  # need to name your id var here
        summarise_(mean = interp(~mean(var), var = as.name(x)))  # See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724124/standard-evaluation-in-dplyr-summarise-on-variable-given-as-a-character-string
    return(result)
}

# Now apply that function to all desired variables --- here, all non-id columns in iris,
# which are columns 1 through 4 --- and then assign the variables names to the elements
# of that list.
agglist <- lapply(names(iris)[1:4], aggregateit)
names(agglist) <- names(iris)[1:4]

# Now write the data frames in that list to a workbook with nice names for the sheets
for (i in 1:length(agglist)) write.xlsx(agglist[[i]], file="filename.xlsx",
    sheetName=names(agglist)[i], append=TRUE)
```

And here's a version that uses `aggregate` in the initial function so you can do the whole thing in base R if you like:

```
aggregateit <- function(variable) {
    var.mean <- aggregate(variable ~ Species, iris, FUN=function(x) mean(x))  # need to swap in your df and id var names
    var.sd <- aggregate(variable ~ Species, iris, FUN=function(x) sd(x)) # ditto
    result <- merge(var.mean, var.sd, by = "Species")  # again for id var
    names(result) <- c("Species", "mean", "sd")  # once more
    return(result)
}

agglist <- lapply(iris[,1:4], aggregateit)

for (i in 1:length(agglist)) write.xlsx(agglist[[i]], file="iris.sumstats.xlsx",
    sheetName=names(agglist)[i], append=TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```