# group_by and selection helpers / standard evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr, non-standard-evaluation

I'm rewriting some Code in a Project where I need to group by (and summarise) a variablename from a character variable, similar to this:

```
test <- mtcars
x <- "gear"
```

This would work with `group_by_` the deprecated standard evaluation version of `group_by` like this:

```
test %>% 
  group_by_(x) %>%
  summarise(mpg=mean(mpg)
```

Is it possible to archive this with `group_by` and quoting and unqouting `x` or can I use selection helpers like `matches` in `group_by`?

I cannot change the way `x` is stored, because other parts of the project still use split-lapply like `split(test, test[, x])` ...

Comment: use `get` ? `test %>% 
    group_by(get(x)) %>%
    summarise(mpg=mean(mpg))`

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944709/using-variable-column-names-in-dplyr-summarise

Comment: If it is not necessary for you to use exactly the `group_by` function, you can try `group_by_at(vars(one_of(x)))`.

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, the link in kath's comment is a dupe.

Comment: @tmfmnk thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Please consider removing the duplicate flag, if I'm not mistaken the `group_by_at solution does not really apply in the possible original post but is exactly what I was looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to a symbol first

```
test %>% 
  group_by(!!rlang::sym(x)) %>%
  summarise(mpg=mean(mpg))
```