# Pass argument to function using plyr/dplyr

Tags: r, function, arguments, dplyr

This problem is similar to a previous [Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function), except that the function calls the `plyr/dplyr` package functions:

Using the example for illustration:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=2:11, C=3:12) 
func <- function(name,dat=df){
        output <- dat %>%
                  select(A,name) %>%
                  arrange(desc(name))
}
```

The following call naturally produces an error:

```
result <- func(B)
```

While passing the arg. as character:

```
result <- func("B")
```

gives:

```
Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
```

**Update**:
Note that `func` also calls the `arrange()` function from `dplyr`. For now, `select_` solved 1/2 of the problem as suggested in the comment.

Using `arrange_(desc(name))` throws this error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : incorrect size (1), expecting : 10

**Update/Edit**: 
As suggested in the comments, a resolution could be:

```
func <- function(name,dat=df){
        output <- dat %>%
                  select_(~A,name) %>%
                  arrange_(interp(~desc(var), var=as.name(name)))
}

result <- func(B)
```

Is it possible to "patch" the following call to `ggplot()` to `func`? This is highly-desirable to automate the process:

```
 plot <-  ggplot(result, aes(x=A, y=B))+
          geom_bar(stat='identity)
```

Comment: Use `select_("A",name)` instead. Also, you don't need that whole piping and `output <-` part just do `func <- function(name, dat = df) select_(dat, "A", name)`

Comment: Thanks David, `select_(~A,name) or select_("A",name)` worked. Could you post the answer?

Comment: Ok, added. Though there is probably some place for improvement.

Comment: Have you seen the update regarding the call to `arrange()`?

Comment: No, just saw now. Btw, why are you using `library(plyr)`? Also, the issue isn't with `arrange_` rather with `desc`

Comment: Actually `dplyr`: I load both. Yep, with `desc`. The issue with `arrange_` can be fixed: `arrange_(as.name(name))` using package `lazyeval`. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724124/standard-evaluation-in-dplyr-summarise-on-variable-given-as-a-character-string).

Comment: Try `dat %>% select_("A", name) %>% arrange_(interp(~ desc(var), var = as.name(name)))`

Comment: Btw, you could solve this very easily without all this `_` and `interp` mess with just base R using `func <- function(name, dat = df) dat[order(-dat[, name]), c("A", name)]`.

Comment: Thanks docendo, works perfect. Can you please post the answer. Thanks David, I agree there are different ways. `dplyr` is compact and handy. I'm glad I learned something new through solving this.

Comment: @remi, I closed it as a duplicate of the question you linked to in the comments.