# dplyr - groupby on multiple columns using variable names

Tags: r, group-by, shiny, dplyr

I am working with R Shiny for some exploratory data analysis. I have two checkbox inputs that contain only the user-selected options. The first checkbox input contains only the categorical variables; the second checkbox contains only numeric variables. Next, I apply a `groupby` on these two selections:

```
var1 <- input$variable1      # Checkbox with categorical variables
var2 <- input$variable2      # Checkbox with numerical variables

v$data <- dataset %>%
  group_by_(var1) %>%
  summarize_(Sum = interp(~sum(x), x = as.name(var2))) %>%
  arrange(desc(Sum))
```

When only one categorical variable is selected, this `groupby` works perfectly. When multiple categorical variables are chosen, this `groupby` returns an array with column names. How do I pass this array of column names to `dplyr`'s `groupby`?

Comment: I have 11 categorical variables when user selects lets say 3 categorical variables it gives me `[1] "dish_name"         "dish_type"        
[3] "user_location_grp" `in `var1` how do I pass this array to groupby.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### dplyr version >1.0

With more recent versions of `dplyr`, you should use `across` along with a tidyselect helper function. See `help("language", "tidyselect")` for a list of all the helper functions. In this case if you want all columns in a character vector, use `all_of()`

```
cols <- c("mpg","hp","wt")
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(across(all_of(cols))) %>% 
   summarize(x=mean(gear))
```

### original answer (older versions of dplyr)

If you have a vector of variable names, you should pass them to the `.dots=` parameter of `group_by_`. For example:

```
mtcars %>% 
   group_by_(.dots=c("mpg","hp","wt")) %>% 
   summarize(x=mean(gear))
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `group_by_()` function is soft-deprecated and will eventually be removed from the `dplyr` package.

Answer (score 11):

With `dplyr 1.0.0`, we have the following possibility based on the "normal" `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)

group_cols <- c("vs", "am")

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(across(all_of(group_cols))) %>% 
  summarize(mean_wt = mean(wt))
```

Comment: is all_of necessary in group_by(across( ?

Comment: In this case, yes.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the helpers from `rlang` package, which is created by the same team that created `dplyr`. When using `dplyr` and other tidyverse packages, you don't have to load the `rlang` packages in order to use those helpers.

Specifically, you can use the `syms` function and the `!!!` function like so:

```
library(dplyr)

group_cols <- c("vs", "am")

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(!!!syms(group_cols)) %>% 
  summarize(mean_wt = mean(wt))
```

This [closely-related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46105537/5373794) explains how the `!!` operator and `sym` function are used for a single column name (i.e. a length-one character vector).

Answer (score 5):

Recent versions of the `dplyr` package include variants of `group_by`, such as `group_by_if` and `group_by_at`. You can use these to perform column selections with syntax that is similar to the `select` function.

Just as you could select a list of columns with `select(my_data, one_of(group_cols))`, you can use `group_by_at` to do the following:

```
library(dplyr)

group_cols <- c("vs", "am")

mtcars %>% 
  group_by_at(.vars = vars(one_of(group_cols))) %>% 
  summarize(mean_wt = mean(wt))
```

Comment: Because these answers are fundamentally different approaches. If users find one approach more helpful than the other, the voting process will make that clear. There's no harm to readers in there being two posts, and I'm happy to field comments and edits to both of them separately. Please see [this relevant post on `meta.stackexchange`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25210) recommending the use of multiple answers in cases such as this.

Comment: *'Scoped verbs (⁠_if⁠, ⁠_at⁠, ⁠_all⁠) have been superseded by the use of pick() or across() in an existing verb. See vignette("colwise") for details.'*

Comment: Yes, good point. `pick()` and `across()` are the best approach until they too ultimately get superseded ;)