# Dynamically selecting multiple columns for group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

Data masking for group_by does not work when there is more than one grouping variable.

Pasting code below

```
grpByCols <- "model"

mpg%>%
  group_by(.data[[grpByCols]])

grpByCols <- c("model", "manufacturer")

mpg%>%
  group_by(.data[[grpByCols]])
```

The first group_by works, the second one fails.

Pasting the run output below

```
> grpByCols <- "model"
> 
> mpg%>%
+   group_by(.data[[grpByCols]])
# A tibble: 234 x 11
# Groups:   model [38]
   manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
 1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
 2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
 3 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
 4 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact
 5 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact
 6 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
 7 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact
 8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact
 9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact
10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact
# … with 224 more rows
> 
> grpByCols <- c("model", "manufacturer")
> 
> mpg%>%
+   group_by(.data[[grpByCols]])
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Must subset the data pronoun with a string.
ℹ Input `..1` is `<unknown>`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas to make this work

Comment: You can group this way `mpg %>% group_by(.[,grpByCols])`, as well.

Comment: @guna I've changed the title to something more suitable, since I don't think it was directly related to masking, but feel free to change back if I have misunderstood.

Comment: Thank you @Kat. I will probably go with the across solution pointed by 

user438383

Comment: [dplyr - groupby on multiple columns using variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487641/dplyr-groupby-on-multiple-columns-using-variable-names)

Answer (score 8):

A simple way is to use the `across()` function from `dplyr`.

```
mpg %>% group_by(across(all_of(grpByCols)))
```

```
# A tibble: 234 × 11
# Groups:   model, manufacturer [38]
   manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans drv     cty   hwy fl    class
   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
 1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto… f        18    29 p     comp…
 2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manu… f        21    29 p     comp…
 3 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manu… f        20    31 p     comp…
 4 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto… f        21    30 p     comp…
 5 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto… f        16    26 p     comp…
 6 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manu… f        18    26 p     comp…
 7 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto… f        18    27 p     comp…
 8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manu… 4        18    26 p     comp…
 9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 auto… 4        16    25 p     comp…
10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manu… 4        20    28 p     comp…
```

Comment: This is Brilliant! I need to dig more into across. Thank you!!

Comment: This should really be `across(all_of(grpByCols))`. You don't see a warning about directly passing a character vector being ambiguous?

Answer (score 5):

We could *unquote* the symbol with `!!`

```
grpByCols <- "model"
mpg%>%
    group_by(!!sym(grpByCols))
```

```
manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
 1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
 2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
 3 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
 4 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact
 5 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact
 6 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
 7 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact
 8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact
 9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact
10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact
# ... with 224 more rows
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following solution. You should use `rlang::syms` which takes strings as input and turn them into symbols and since the output is a list of length 2 (corresponding to the length of input), we use big bang operator `!!!` to splice the elements of the list, meaning that they each become one single argument:

```
library(rlang)

grpByCols <- c("model", "manufacturer")

mpg %>%
  group_by(!!!syms(grpByCols))

# A tibble: 234 x 11
# Groups:   model, manufacturer [38]
   manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
 1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
 2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
 3 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
 4 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact
 5 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact
 6 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
 7 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact
 8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact
 9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact
10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact
# ... with 224 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you! I probably would use the across solution. Since the new tidyverse grammar seems to recommend away from !!!

Answer (score 3):

Using `cur_data()`

```
library(dplyr)
mpg %>% 
     group_by(cur_data()[grpByCols])
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 234 x 11
# Groups:   model, manufacturer [38]
   manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
 1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
 2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
 3 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
 4 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact
 5 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact
 6 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
 7 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact
 8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact
 9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact
10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact
# … with 224 more rows
```