# Use function in groupby with variable column name in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Category = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)), Value = rnorm(6))
df
 Category       Value
1        A -0.94968814
2        A  2.56687061
3        A -0.15665153
4        B -0.47647105
5        B  0.83015076
6        B -0.03744522
```

Now I want to add another column which is the mean per Category. This can be done with the dplyr package really easy:

```
df %>% group_by(Category) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(Value))
```

Now in piece of code my problem is: I can't use `mean(Value)`, but I have a variable name that knows the column name: `columnName = "Value"`
But this unfortunately won't work:

```
columnName = "Value"

df %>% group_by(Category) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(columnName))
```

> Warning messages: 1: In mean.default("Value") :   argument is not
>   numeric or logical: returning NA 2: In mean.default("Value") :
>   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

How can I pass the column name with the variable?

Comment: `mean(df[,columnName])` this code worked for me, when using the same variables as you did.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. It has to be mean of the groups, not the mean of the column.

Comment: It is not using the package `dplyr` but it works like this:   `tapply(df[,columnName],df$Category, mean)`

Comment: please use `set.seed` when using such functions as `rnorm` to create data frames so we can double check results

Comment: This is called *standard evaluation*. There hundreds are of dupes regarding this on SO. Please read `vignette("nse")`. One way to achieve this is `library(lazyeval) ; dots <- interp(~ mean(columnName), columnName = as.name("Value")) ; df %>% group_by(Category) %>% summarise_(.dots = dots)`

Comment: See also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724124/standard-evaluation-in-dplyr-summarise-on-variable-given-as-a-character-string

Answer (score 2):

We can use `get` with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(get(columnName)~Category, df, mean)

#    Category get(columnName)
#1        A      -0.5490751
#2        B      -0.2594670
```

Comment: This works thanks! But I was looking for a solution within the dplyr package. Do you know if that is possible too?