# How to use standard evaluation in dplyr summarise_

Tags: r, dplyr

I have looked at several places but I just can't figure out how to do this. It looks like it has changed a few times so even more confusing

I want to summarise the NumOfBx by Endoscopist as part of a function. I have the following dataframe

```
vv <- structure(list(Endoscopist = c("John Boy ", "Jupi Ter ", "Jupi Ter ", 
"John Boy ", "John Boy ", "John Boy ", "Mar Gret ", "John Boy ", 
"Mar Gret ", "Phil Ip ", "Phil Ip "), NumbOfBx = c(2, 4, NA, 
2, 12, 12, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA)), row.names = 100:110, .Names = c("Endoscopist", 
"NumbOfBx"), class = "data.frame")
```

My function is:

```
NumBx <- function(x, y, z) {
  x <- data.frame(x)
  x <- x[!is.na(x[,y]), ]
  NumBxPlot <- x %>% group_by_(z) %>% summarise(avg = mean(y, na.rm = T))
}
```

which I call with:

```
NumBx(vv,"Endoscopist","NumOfBx)
```

This gives me the error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(y, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(y, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(y, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I changed the function to use `summarise_`

but I get the same thing. Then I realised the need for `summarise_` specifically (as opposed to `group_by_`) needing a standard evaluations and I tried this (from [this stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724124/standard-evaluation-in-dplyr-summarise-on-variable-given-as-a-character-string))

```
library(lazyeval)
NumBx <- function(x, y, z) {
  x <- data.frame(x)
  x <- x[!is.na(x[,y]), ]
  NumBxPlot <- x %>% group_by_(z) %>% 
      summarise_(sum_val = interp(~mean(y, na.rm = TRUE), var = as.name(y)))
```

but I still get the same error of:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(y, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(y, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(y, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

My intended output is:

```
Endoscopist   Avg
Jupi Ter       4
John Boy       28
Phil Ip        3
```

Comment: Try using `get(y)` in your summarise function.  I tested this and got the same error when trying to use a variable that refers to a column name.  The `get()` function solved it for me. Might need to do the same in your `group_by`

Answer (score 2):

Using [rlang](https://github.com/hadley/rlang) (the replacement for lazyeval), you could do

```r
library(dplyr)

vv <- structure(list(Endoscopist = c("John Boy ", "Jupi Ter ", "Jupi Ter ", "John Boy ", "John Boy ", "John Boy ", "Mar Gret ", "John Boy ", "Mar Gret ", "Phil Ip ", "Phil Ip "), 
                     NumbOfBx = c(2, 4, NA, 2, 12, 12, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA)), 
                row.names = 100:110, .Names = c("Endoscopist", "NumbOfBx"), class = "data.frame")

num_bx <- function(.data, group, variable) {
    group <- enquo(group)
    variable <- enquo(variable)

    .data %>% 
        tidyr::drop_na(!!variable) %>% 
        group_by(!!group) %>% 
        summarise(avg = mean(!!variable))
}

vv %>% num_bx(Endoscopist, NumbOfBx)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Endoscopist   avg
#>         <chr> <dbl>
#> 1   John Boy      7
#> 2   Jupi Ter      4
#> 3    Phil Ip      3
```

or if you want to keep it as strings instead of unquoted names,

```r
num_bx <- function(.data, group, variable) {
    group <- rlang::sym(group)
    variable <- rlang::sym(variable)

    .data %>% 
        tidyr::drop_na(!!variable) %>% 
        group_by(!!group) %>% 
        summarise(avg = mean(!!variable))
}

vv %>% num_bx("Endoscopist", "NumbOfBx")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Endoscopist   avg
#>         <chr> <dbl>
#> 1   John Boy      7
#> 2   Jupi Ter      4
#> 3    Phil Ip      3
```

Comment: @aosmith Oops, yep, the old package was called lazyeval. "tidy eval" is just a concept, not a package. Fixed above.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [dplyr programming vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), define your function as follows:

```
NumBx <- function( x, y, z )
{
    yy <- enquo( y )
    zz <- enquo( z )

    data.frame(x) %>% filter( !is.na(!!yy) ) %>% group_by( !!zz ) %>%
        summarize( avg = mean(!!yy) )
}
```

You can now call it as:

```
NumBx( vv, NumbOfBx, Endoscopist )
#   Endoscopist   avg
#         <chr> <dbl>
# 1   John Boy      7
# 2   Jupi Ter      4
# 3    Phil Ip      3
```

Some notes:

1. The order of arguments in your call seemed reversed. You want to group by `z`, but you were passing `NumbOfBx` as the `z` argument.
2. `na.rm=TRUE` is redundant. You are already filtering out the rows, where the `y` variable is NA.
3. The mean of `John Boy` should be `7`, not `28` (the value stated in your intended output).