# How to pass a column name as parameter to a function?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a toy example:

```
df <- data.frame(user=c('a','b'), rating=c(1,2), age=c(17,33))

rating <- function(df, var){x <- df %>% summarise(sum(var))}

rating(df,age)
```

When I execute the function, I get the following error:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : object 'age' not found

How to pass a column name as parameter to the function?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26724721/322912

Comment: It's a bit outdated, i am going to try what udden is suggesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(user=c('a','b'), 
                 rating=c(1,2), 
                 age=c(17,33))

rating <- function(df, var){
  var <- enquo(var)
  df %>% summarise(sum(!!var))
  }

x <- rating(df,age)
```

Comment: Error in enquo(var) : could not find function "enquo"

Comment: Try installing dplyr again. The code uses features from the latest release: https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/06/13/dplyr-0-7-0/

Comment: Thanks, it's working.