# Using a character for variable name in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

There is a lot of stuff out there about how to do this (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724124/standard-evaluation-in-dplyr-summarise-on-variable-given-as-a-character-string?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [the dplyr vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)), but I can't understand much of it nor make any of it work.

If I want a quick summary of data I can accomplish this easily via

```
d <- data.frame(g = rep(c("A", "B"),10), vNom = rnorm(20,0,1))

(dTab <- d %>% group_by(g) %>% summarise(m = mean(vNom)))
```

I need to be able to get the same result with a character string, using either:

```
dTab <- d %>% group_by(g) %>% summarise(m = mean("vNom"))
```

or

```
dTab <- d %>% group_by(g) %>% summarise_(m = mean("vNom"))
```

But, of course neither work. I won't go through the dizzying array of `!!`, `UQ`, and `quo()`operators I have tried. It seems like such a simple task.

Comment: I've not really looked into it, but maybe `summarise(m = mean(!!sym("vNom")))` as suggested in the question you linked to?

Comment: Try `get` : `d %>% group_by(g) %>% summarise(m = mean(get("vNom")))`