# How to specify a column name in ddply via character variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, rlang, tidyeval

I have a tibble/dataframe with

```
sample_id     condition     state
---------------------------------
sample1       case          val1
sample1       case          val2
sample1       case          val3
sample2       control       val1
sample2       control       val2
sample2       control       val3
```

The dataframe is generated within a for loop for different states. Hence, every dataframe has a different name for the state column.

I want to group the data by `sample_id` and calculate the median of the state column such that every unique `sample_id` has a single median value. The output should be like below...

```
sample_id     condition     state
---------------------------------
sample1       case          median
sample2       control       median
```

I am trying the command below; it is working if give the name of the column, but I am not able to pass the name via the state character variable. I tried `ensym(state)` and `!!ensym(state)`, but they all are throwing errors.

```
ddply(dat_state, .(sample_id), summarize,  condition=unique(condition), state_exp=median(ensym(state)))
```

Comment: Just want to point out that `ddply` comes from `plyr`, which has been deprecated for a few years now. You can do this with `dplyr` functions: just group by the first two columns and summarize the third as the median. To do something like this with the column name as a variable, you can use tidyeval in a function. You're trying to do this with something like `x <- "state"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [standard evaluation in dplyr: summarise a variable given as a character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724124/standard-evaluation-in-dplyr-summarise-a-variable-given-as-a-character-string)

Comment: @camille `plyr` has not been deprecated. It is retired, meaning we continue to maintain it on CRAN indefinitely without adding new features.

Comment: @LionelHenry true, I used the wrong term. But it's fair to encourage people to move toward the packages taking its place, right?

Comment: yup totally fair, especially for new packages and scripts. I just wanted to make sure people are not going to get the wrong impression that plyr might disappear from CRAN anytime soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for putting effort into answering my question. With your suggestions, I have found the solution. Below is the code to what I was trying to achieve by grouping `sample_id` and `condition` and passing `state` through a variable.

```
state_mark <- c("pPCLg2", "STAT1", "STAT5", "AKT")

for(state in state_mark){
    dat_state <- dat_clust_stim[,c("sample_id", "condition", state)]

    # I had to use !!ensym() to convert a character to a symbol.
    dat_med <- group_by(dat_state, sample_id, condition) %>% 
               summarise(med = median(!!ensym(state)))

    dat_med <- ungroup(dat_med)
    x <- dat_med[dat_med$condition == "case", "med"]
    y <- dat_med[dat_med$condition == "control", "med"]
    t_test <- t.test(x$med, y$med)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As camille notes above, this is easier in dplyr. Basic syntax (not yet addressing your question):

```
my_df %>% 
  group_by(sample_id, condition) %>% 
  summarize(state = median(state))
```

Note that syntax will give you values for every unique `sample_id`-`condition` pair. Which isn't an issue in your example, since every `sample_id` has the same `condition`, but just something to be aware of.

On to your question... It's not quite clear to me how you're planning to pass the state name to your calculation. But a couple ways you can handle this. One is to use dplyr's "rename" function:

```
x <- "Massachusetts"
my_df %>% 
  rename(state = x) %>% 
  group_by(sample_id, condition) %>% 
  summarize(state = median(state))
```

The (probably more proper) way to do this is to write a function using dplyr's "tidyeval" syntax:

```
myfunc <- function(df, state_name) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(sample_id, condition) %>% 
    summarize(state = median({{state_name}}))
}

myfunc(my_df, Massachusetts) # Note: Unquoted state name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay old-fashioned, you can use the `eval(parse(text=expression))` idiom:

```
ddply(dat_state, .(sample_id), summarize, 
      state_exp = eval(parse(text = paste("median(",state,")"))))
```

No fancy operators but mind the parentheses!