# R: What is the expected output of passing a character vector to dplyr::all_of()?

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, summarize, data-wrangling

I am trying to understand the expected output of `dplyr::group_by()` in conjunction with the use of `dplyr::all_of()`. My understanding is that using `dplyr::all_of()` should convert character vectors containing variable names to the bare names so that `group_by()`, but this doesn't appear to happen.

Below, I generate some fake data, pass different objects to `group_by()` with(out) `all_of()` and calculate the number of observations in each group.  In the example, passing a single bare column name without `dplyr::all_of()` produces the correct output: one row per unique value of the column. However, passing character vectors or using `dplyr::all_of()` produces incorrect output: one row regardless of the number of values in a column.

What is expected when using `all_of` and how might I alternatively pass a character vector to `group_by` to process as a vector of bare names?

```
library(dplyr)

# Create a 20-row data.frame with
# 2 variables each with 2 unique values.
df <- data.frame(var = rep(c("a", "b"), 10),
                 bar = rep(c(1, 2), 20))

# Output 1: 2x2 tibble - GOOD
df %>% group_by(var) %>% summarize(n = n())

# Output 2: 1x2 tibble - BAD
foo <- "var"
df %>% group_by(all_of(foo)) %>% summarize(n = n())

# Output 3: 1x2 tibble
df %>% group_by("var") %>% summarize(n = n())

# Output 4: Error in_var not found - BAD
foo2 <- list("var", "bar")
lapply(foo2, function(in_var) {
  df %>%
    group_by(in_var) %>%
    summarize(n = n())
})

# Output 5: list of length 2 where
# each element is a 1x2 tibble - BAD
foo2 <- list("var", "bar")
lapply(foo2, function(in_var) {
  df %>%
    group_by(all_of(in_var)) %>%
    summarize(n = n())
})
```

Comment: an option for your second question is using `group_by` with `across` if you're using dplyr >= 1.0.0

Comment: I think you want `df %>% group_by(across(all_of(foo))) %>% summarize(n = n())` with the latest versions of `dplyr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `group_by_at`

```
lapply(foo2, function(in_var) df %>% 
      group_by_at(all_of(in_var)) %>% 
      summarise(n = n()))
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  var       n
#* <chr> <int>
#1 a        20
#2 b        20

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#    bar     n
#* <dbl> <int>
#1     1    20
#2     2    20
```

---

As `across` replaces some of the functionality of `group_by_at`, we can use it instead with `all_of`:

```
lapply(foo2, function(in_var) df %>% 
      group_by(across(all_of(in_var))) %>% 
      summarise(n = n()))
```

---

Or convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
lapply(foo2, function(in_var) df %>% 
      group_by(!! rlang::sym(in_var)) %>% 
      summarise(n = n()))
```

---

Or use `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(foo2, ~ df %>%
              group_by(!! rlang::sym(.x)) %>%
              summarise(n = n()))
```

---

Or instead of `group_by`, it can be `count`

```
map(foo2, ~ df %>%
              count(across(all_of(.x))))
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. I think the issue was in my understanding of why `across()` is necessary. Still not clear to me why `group_by` needs `across()` to use `all_of` appropriately. I know this is a scoping issue. If there is a good link to read for how different functions scope in `dplyr`, would be welcome.

Comment: @user3614648 you may check the `vignette` of dplyr which will have information regarding those new functionalities

Answer (score 1):

To add to @akrun's answers of mutliple ways to achieve the desired output - my understanding of `all_of()` is that, it is a helper for selection of variables stored as character for `dplyr` function and uses `vctrs` underneath. Compared to `any_of()` which is a less strict version of `all_of()` and some convenient use cases.
reading the `?tidyselect::all_off()` is helpful. This page is also helpful to keep up with changes in `dplyr` and tidy evaluation https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html.

The scoped `dplyr` verbs are being superceded in the future with `across` based on decisions by the devs at RStudio. See `?group_by_at()` or other `*_if`, `*_at`, `*_all` documentation. So I guess it really depends on what version of `dplyr` you are using in your workflow and what works best for you.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724124/standard-evaluation-in-dplyr-summarise-a-variable-given-as-a-character-string) also gives context of changes in solutions over time with passing characters into `dplyr` functions, and there's probably more posts out there.