# dplyr::manip: How to use string arguments (holding colnames) instead of column names

Tags: r, dplyr

The title describes pretty much what I want:

instead of:

```
filter(mtcars, cyl == 8)
```

I would like to use:

```
var <- "cyl"
filter(mtcars, var == 8)  # pseudocode
```

just like

```
mtcars[which(mtcars[,var]==8),]
```

I see that there are functions like
`starts_with()`
but IMHO none really suits for above rather simple application.

Comment: just saw that this is somewhat related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208801/group-by-multiple-columns-in-dplyr-using-string-vector-input

Comment: It's not currently supported, but I'm working on it: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/352

Comment: This feature is now implemented. No workaround neccessary. To get around non-standard evaluation, use the `manip_()` flavor, e.g. `filter_()`. `vignette("nse")` elaborates on that. Thanks @hadley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mtcars %>% do(filter(., .[[var]] == 8))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
eval(substitute(filter(mtcars, var == 8),list(var=as.name(var))))%>%
head(2)
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 2 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4

filter(mtcars, get(var, envir=as.environment(mtcars)) == 8) #should also work but not recommended
```

Comment: From you answer I conclude that currently dplyr does not support string arguments. Right?

Comment: @Jan, Yes, if i am not mistaken.

Comment: Well, then this kind of answers my question. Although not in a very satisfactory manner. @akrun Not your fault, though. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more way with `do.call`:

```
do.call(filter, list(mtcars, bquote(.(as.name(var)) == 8)))
```