# How do you group values in one column for each unique value in another R?

Tags: r, aggregate

This is an elementary question, but I have been stuck on it for quite some time. I'm trying to group the values in ColumnB but only within each value in ColumnA.

The initial data frame would be something like:

```
ColumnA = c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
ColumnB = c("f","g","g","f","f","h")
df <- data.frame(ColumnA,ColumnB)
```

```html
ColumnA    ColumnB
    1         f
    1         g
    1         g
    2         f
    2         f
    2         h
```

The result would be:

```html
ColumnA    ColumnB
    1         f
    1         g
    2         f
    2         h
```

(One of the methods I tried using was with `dplyr` using: `group_by(df, ColumnB)`, but that attempt was unsuccessful.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try `duplicated`

```
df[!duplicated(df),]
#   ColumnA ColumnB
#1       1       f
#2       1       g
#4       2       f
#6       2       h
```

If needed, this would also give the logical index of rows.

Answer (score 8):

The `unique` function is uniquely suited (no pun intended) to solve your problem:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), v2=c("f", "g", "g", "f", "f", "h"))
df <- unique(df)

> df1
  v1 v2
1  1  f
2  1  g
4  2  f
6  2  h
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, you'd want to perform an operation after grouping them; the grouping alone does not collapse the rows.  You could calculate something with `summarise()`, pick one row within the group based on a variable, etc.  Here's an example with `slice()` to select the first record within each group combination:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ColumnA, ColumnB) %>%
  slice(1) # select the first row within each group combination

Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
Groups: ColumnA, ColumnB

  ColumnA ColumnB
1       1       f
2       1       g
3       2       f
4       2       h
```

Comment: Thank you Sam for the response--If more than one row has to be grouped however, is there an efficient method to group each one at once?

Comment: Is your question about the grouping variables (columns) or the rows within subgroups? If you want to select a different row or multiple rows within your subgroup, you can edit the last line above; if you want to group by many columns and don't want to type them out, you can pass them as a variable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208801/group-by-multiple-columns-in-dplyr-using-string-vector-input