# How can I reorder columns in a 'canonical' way after mutate_each or summarise_each?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-colnames

Take the following example.

```
library(dplyr)
temp <- data.frame(lapply(1:3, function(i) rnorm(5, 0, 1)))
names(temp) <- paste0("X", 1:3)

temp_each <-
    temp %>%
    mutate_each(funs(mean, median))
```

Examining the names of `temp_each`, we see that

```
> names(temp_each)
[1] "X1"        "X2"        "X3"        "X1_mean"   "X2_mean"   "X3_mean"   "X1_median" "X2_median" "X3_median"
```

that is, the final columns are in groups of three, always ordered  `X1`, `X2`, `X3` + the function applied.

However, I would like it to look like this

```
[1] "X1"        "X1_mean"   "X1_median" "X2"        "X2_mean"   "X2_median" "X3"        "X3_mean"   "X3_median"
```

Does anyone know how to implement this, preferably using `dplyr`, for a data frame with many many columns and arbitrary column names?

Comment: You can just reorder the columns, by sorting the names in alphabetical order? `temp_each[,order(names(temp_each))]` does that achieve what you were after?

Comment: that's a good interim solution, but that may not necessary preserve the ordering of the original names, if they are not `X1`, `X2`, etc... I reworded the question slightly, thanks

Comment: You may want to check `mixedorder` from gtools

Comment: As long as you can write some custom function to define the order of the names, sounds good.

Comment: I am particularly struggling to implement this as part of a `select` step.

Answer (score 5):

Here you could use `mixedorder` from `gtools`

```
library(gtools)
temp_each[,mixedorder(colnames(temp_each))]

#           X1    X1_mean  X1_median         X2    X2_mean  X2_median
#1  0.28285115 -0.4369067 0.08556155 -0.9402162 -0.9857593 -0.7676634
#2 -1.29193398 -0.4369067 0.08556155 -0.5442052 -0.9857593 -0.7676634
#3 -1.42261044 -0.4369067 0.08556155 -0.7676634 -0.9857593 -0.7676634
#4  0.16159810 -0.4369067 0.08556155 -2.2270920 -0.9857593 -0.7676634
#5  0.08556155 -0.4369067 0.08556155 -0.4496198 -0.9857593 -0.7676634
#           X3   X3_mean   X3_median
#1  0.04606554 0.0923336 -0.08168136
#2 -0.08168136 0.0923336 -0.08168136
#3  0.90535333 0.0923336 -0.08168136
#4 -0.15699052 0.0923336 -0.08168136
#5 -0.25107897 0.0923336 -0.08168136
```

Answer (score 2):

With base `R` you could try this:

```
> temp_each[order(colnames(temp_each))]
#          X1    X1_mean X1_median         X2   X2_mean  X2_median         X3  X3_mean X3_median
#    1  0.4142743 -0.4389318 -0.285517  1.8662158 0.3534017 -0.2308971  1.3593561 0.478106 0.6306579
#    2 -0.8031115 -0.4389318 -0.285517 -0.2308971 0.3534017 -0.2308971 -0.6160166 0.478106 0.6306579
#    3 -1.8729143 -0.4389318 -0.285517  1.0171626 0.3534017 -0.2308971  0.2634524 0.478106 0.6306579
#    4  0.3526097 -0.4389318 -0.285517 -0.6378480 0.3534017 -0.2308971  0.6306579 0.478106 0.6306579
#    5 -0.2855170 -0.4389318 -0.285517 -0.2476247 0.3534017 -0.2308971  0.7530800 0.478106 0.6306579
```

Comment: this won't produce the desired output if there are columns like X10, X20 ans so on

Comment: I agree. In that case one could add leading zeros in front of the index number for smaller numbers by means of regexp manipulation. While this is possible, your solution seems easier if it can handle those cases automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for the answers using base `R` or otherwise.

This is my preferred base `R` solution.

```
old_names <- names(temp)
new_names <- unlist(lapply(old_names, function(old_name) paste0(old_name, c("_mean", "_median"))))
temp_each <- temp_each[new_names]
```

However, I have now worked out how to do it in `dplyr` using standard evaluation, from this answer: [Group by multiple columns in dplyr, using string vector input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208801/group-by-multiple-columns-in-dplyr-using-string-vector-input)

It is rather convoluted.

```
temp <- data.frame(lapply(1:3, function(i) rnorm(5, 0, 1)))
names(temp) <- paste0("X", 1:3)

old_names <- names(temp)
new_names <- unlist(lapply(old_names, function(old_name) paste0(old_name, c("_mean", "_median"))))


temp_each <-
    temp %>%
    mutate_each(funs(mean, median)) %>%
    select_(.dots = lapply(new_names, as.symbol))
```