# How to group by all but one columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I tell `group_by` to group the data by all columns except a given one?

With `aggregate`, it would be `aggregate(x ~ ., ...)`.

I tried `group_by(data, -x)`, but that groups by the negative-of-x (i.e. the same as grouping by x).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28182288/4604054 is one way to do this, its quite long winded in comparison to aggregate.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

### dplyr version 1.0+

In dplyr 1.0.0 coming up, the `_at` functions are falling into the *superseded lifecycle* (i.e. while they remain in `dplyr` for the foreseeable future, there are now better alternatives that are more actively developed). The new way to accomplish this is via the `across` function:

```
df %>%
  group_by(across(c(-hp)))
```

---

### dplyr v 0.7+

A small update on this question because I stumbled across this myself and found an elegant solution with current version of `dplyr` (0.7.4):
Inside `group_by_at()`, you can supply the names of columns the same way as in the `select()` function using `vars()`. This enables us to group by everything but one column (`hp` in this example) by writing:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = "car")
df %>% group_by_at(vars(-hp))
```

Comment: You may even supply several columns to ignore: `df %>% group_by_at(vars(-hp, -cyl))` without needing to use the c() construct. Super nice!

Comment: it even works `group_by(across(!hp)`. Would be great if this could be marked as the answer now.

Answer (score 40):

Building on the @eipi10's dplyr 0.7.0 edit, `group_by_at` appears to be the right function for this job. However, if you are simply looking to omit column "x", then you can use:

```
new2.0 <- dat %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-x)) %>%
  summarize(mean_value = mean(value))
```

Using @eipi10's example data:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(492)
dat <- data.frame(value = rnorm(1000),
             g1 = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE),
             g2 = sample(letters, 1000, replace = TRUE),
             g3 = sample(1:10, replace = TRUE),
             other = sample(c("red", "green", "black"), 1000, replace = TRUE))

new <- dat %>% 
  group_by_at(names(dat)[-grep("value", names(dat))]) %>%
  summarise(meanValue = mean(value))


new2.0 <- dat %>% 
  group_by_at(vars(-value)) %>% 
  summarize(meanValue = mean(value))

identical(new, new2.0)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 35):

You can do this using standard evaluation (`group_by_` instead of `group_by`):

```
# Fake data
set.seed(492)
dat = data.frame(value=rnorm(1000), g1=sample(LETTERS,1000,replace=TRUE),
                 g2=sample(letters,1000,replace=TRUE), g3=sample(1:10, replace=TRUE),
                 other=sample(c("red","green","black"),1000,replace=TRUE))

dat %>% group_by_(.dots=names(dat)[-grep("value", names(dat))]) %>%
  summarise(meanValue=mean(value))
```

> ```
>        g1     g2    g3  other   meanValue
>    <fctr> <fctr> <int> <fctr>       <dbl>
> 1       A      a     2  green  0.89281475
> 2       A      b     2    red -0.03558775
> 3       A      b     5  black -1.79184218
> 4       A      c    10  black  0.17518610
> 5       A      e     5  black  0.25830392
> ...
> ```

See [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) for more on standard vs. non-standard evaluation in `dplyr`.

#### UPDATE for `dplyr` 0.7.0

To address @ÖmerAn's comment: It looks like `group_by_at` is the way to go in `dplyr` 0.7.0 (someone please correct me if I'm wrong about this). For example:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by_at(setdiff(names(dat), "value")) %>%
  summarise(meanValue=mean(value))
```

> ```
> # Groups:   g1, g2, g3 [?]
>        g1     g2    g3  other   meanValue
>    <fctr> <fctr> <int> <fctr>       <dbl>
>  1      A      a     2  green  0.89281475
>  2      A      b     2    red -0.03558775
>  3      A      b     5  black -1.79184218
>  4      A      c    10  black  0.17518610
>  5      A      e     5  black  0.25830392
>  6      A      e     5    red -0.81879788
>  7      A      e     7  green  0.30836054
>  8      A      f     2  green  0.05537047
>  9      A      g     1  black  1.00156405
> 10      A      g    10  black  1.26884303
> # ... with 949 more rows
> ```

Let's confirm both methods give the same output (in `dplyr` 0.7.0):

```
new = dat %>% 
  group_by_at(setdiff(names(dat), "value")) %>%
  summarise(meanValue=mean(value))

old = dat %>% 
  group_by_(.dots=names(dat)[-grep("value", names(dat))]) %>%
  summarise(meanValue=mean(value))

identical(old, new)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Instead of `names(dat)[-grep("value", names(dat))]`, you can also use `setdiff(names(dat), "value")`

Comment: Although it's risker, I guess you could even select by position: `names(dat)[-1]`. We're golfing, right? :)

Comment: Certainly also a valid option :-)

Comment: Also, if you want to summarise all columns at once use `dplyr::summarise_each(funs(mean))`

Comment: How to do this in the newest version of `dplyr 0.7.0` which claims the SE versions of the verbs are now deprecated? https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/releases

Comment: As @eipi10 pointed out, is there an advantage to `group_by_at` over chaining `select(-value) %>% group_by()`? I thought group_by_at might keep the excluded column, but it drops the excluded column.