# Location letters in a horizontal line in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data

```
df<-read.table (text=" ID   Time
A   55
B   55
C   45
D   55
E   70
F   55
G   56
H   56
I   49
J   56
K   70
L   55
M   56
N   56
P   48
Q   55
R   63
S   55
T   49
U   45


", header=TRUE)
```

I want to plot the location of ID on a horizontal line.  I want also to calculate the average time and show it in the line.  This gives me a plot like this

[image]

Comment: With classic graphics it would be: `seqno <- ave(df$Time, df$Time, FUN = seq_along);
plot(seqno ~ Time, df, pch = df$ID, ylim = c(1, 20), ylab = "", axes = FALSE);
axis(1);
mu <- mean(df$Time);
abline(v = mu, col = "red");
text(mu, 20, paste("Avg time:", mu), adj = -0.1, col = "red")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach. You can smartly arrange your data, group by time and create a y coordinate based on row number. With that you can sketch the plot. The average line and its label can be added with `annotate()` and `geom_vline()`. Here the code using `geom_text()` and some `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
df %>%
  arrange(Time) %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  mutate(y=row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Time))+
  geom_text(aes(y=y,label=ID),size=3,fontface='bold')+
  geom_vline(data=df%>% summarise(Time=mean(Time)),aes(xintercept=Time),color='red')+
  theme_bw()+
  annotate(geom='text',
           x=df%>% summarise(Time=mean(Time)) %>% pull(Time)+3,
           label=paste0('Avg is ',df%>% summarise(Time=mean(Time)) %>% pull(Time)),
           y=7,fontface='bold',size=3)
```

Output:

[image]

And if you want to go around perfection in terms of customization:

```
#Plot 2
df %>%
  arrange(Time) %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  mutate(y=row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Time))+
  geom_text(aes(y=y,label=ID),size=3,fontface='bold')+
  geom_vline(data=df%>% summarise(Time=mean(Time)),aes(xintercept=Time),color='red')+
  theme_bw()+
  annotate(geom='text',
           x=df%>% summarise(Time=mean(Time)) %>% pull(Time)+3,
           label=paste0('Avg is ',df%>% summarise(Time=mean(Time)) %>% pull(Time)),
           y=7,fontface='bold',size=3)+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

To remove y-axis try this:

```
#Plot 3
df %>%
  arrange(Time) %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  mutate(y=row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Time))+
  geom_text(aes(y=y,label=ID),size=3,fontface='bold')+
  geom_vline(data=df%>% summarise(Time=mean(Time)),aes(xintercept=Time),color='red')+
  theme_bw()+
  annotate(geom='text',
           x=df%>% summarise(Time=mean(Time)) %>% pull(Time)+3,
           label=paste0('Avg is ',df%>% summarise(Time=mean(Time)) %>% pull(Time)),
           y=7,fontface='bold',size=3)+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())+ylab('')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, How I can just clear y-axis values ( y, 2,4,6,). Is it possible?

Comment: @user330 I have updated the solution with a code in the end. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Can you help here Duck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002307/shiny-r-using-input-variables-for-dynamic-dplyr-creation-of-datatables