# Why does group_by_at() with a string vector fail when inside a function?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I have a workflow where I supply a vector of strings representing column names to a function that uses group_by on those columns. It works when I test it with one column name, but fails when I pass it multiples.

The basic setup is this:

```
group_summs <- function(df, grouping_vars) {

  if(length(grouping_vars == 1)) {

    group_var <- ensym(grouping_vars)

    df %>%
      group_by(!! group_var) %>% 
      summarise(n_test = n())

  } else {

    group_vars <- grouping_vars

    df %>% 
      group_by_at(.vars = group_vars) %>% 
      summarise(n_test = n())

  }
}

#Single column test
flights <- nycflights13::flights
col_test <- c("origin")

#This Works
group_summs(flights, col_test)

#Multiple columns test
col_test_2 <- c("origin", "carrier")

#This fails
group_summs(flights, col_Test_2)
```

So as a test I can pass a single column name and have it run, but when I run it with multiples I get an rlang error.

"Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
Called from: rlang::abort(x)"

What I really don't get is why the multiple column example runs correctly outside of the function as in:

```
#Runs just fine
col_test_2 <- c("origin", "carrier")
flights %>% group_by_at(.vars = col_test_2) %>% summarise(n_test = n())
```

Is there something about the function environment that I am not understanding, or is this a buggy behavior?

I am using dplyr (0.8.3) and rlang (0.4.0).

This question is very similar to [Group by multiple columns in dplyr, using string vector input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208801/group-by-multiple-columns-in-dplyr-using-string-vector-input/44954739) but the solutions on that question result in the same error so I wonder if there is now a more recent solution (Their current solution from 2017).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is not correct

```
length(grouping_vars == 1)
```

It should be

```
length(grouping_vars) == 1
```

-fullcode

```
group_summs <- function(df, grouping_vars) {

  if(length(grouping_vars) == 1) {

    group_var <- ensym(grouping_vars)

    df %>%
      group_by(!! group_var) %>% 
      summarise(n_test = n())

  } else {

    group_vars <- grouping_vars

    df %>% 
      group_by_at(.vars = group_vars) %>% 
      summarise(n_test = n())

  }
}

group_summs(flights, col_test_2)
# A tibble: 35 x 3
# Groups:   origin [3]
#   origin carrier n_test
#   <chr>  <chr>    <int>
# 1 EWR    9E        1268
# 2 EWR    AA        3487
# 3 EWR    AS         714
# 4 EWR    B6        6557
# 5 EWR    DL        4342
# 6 EWR    EV       43939
# 7 EWR    MQ        2276
# 8 EWR    OO           6
# 9 EWR    UA       46087
#10 EWR    US        4405
# … with 25 more rows

group_summs(flights, col_test)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  origin n_test
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 EWR    120835
#2 JFK    111279
#3 LGA    104662
```

---

However, the condition is not at all required as the `group_by_at` can length >=1

```
group_summs2 <- function(df, grouping_vars) {


    group_vars <- grouping_vars

    df %>% 
      group_by_at(.vars = group_vars) %>% 
      summarise(n_test = n())


}



group_summs2(flights, col_test)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  origin n_test
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 EWR    120835
#2 JFK    111279
#3 LGA    104662

group_summs2(flights, col_test_2)
# A tibble: 35 x 3
# Groups:   origin [3]
#   origin carrier n_test
#   <chr>  <chr>    <int>
# 1 EWR    9E        1268
# 2 EWR    AA        3487
# 3 EWR    AS         714
# 4 EWR    B6        6557
# 5 EWR    DL        4342
# 6 EWR    EV       43939
# 7 EWR    MQ        2276
# 8 EWR    OO           6
# 9 EWR    UA       46087
#10 EWR    US        4405
# … with 25 more rows
```

Comment: So since the solution (thanks by the way) is almost irrelevant to the title and setup of the question, is it beneficial to keep it up the way it is?

Comment: @adamkemberling  You can keep it because the solution gives multiple ways to solve it.  It will help in clarifying some conceptss