# YAML list of parameters to group_by function

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown

I have a vector of characters called splits in my markdown YAML and I want to pass all of those parameters to dplyr group_by function.

```
    ---
title: ""
params:
  splits: ['split1','split2','split3','split4','split5','split6']
---

data %>% group_by(params$splits)
```

where I get the error

```
 Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`
```

I tried using *vars()* but it does not give me a dataframe with all the columns mentioned in splits which is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by the help of `vars(one_of())` mentioned in:

[Group by multiple columns in dplyr, using string vector input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208801/group-by-multiple-columns-in-dplyr-using-string-vector-input)